# What is the name of this photographer?

Tags: art, photography

He was known for (I believe) large format, black and white photographs of men and women, often in suits or business attire in sort of distorted, strange poses -- very angular, abnormal body positions.

I believe it was an Italian photographer, working in the 80's, and his last name starts with an 'M' but I could be wrong. I cannot remember, and it's driving me crazy!

Comment: So this is art photography rather than fashion photography?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Robert Longo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Longo) and the [Men in the Cities](https://www.google.com/search?q=robert+longo+men+in+cities&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi0moO3jeL0AhWNnJ4KHeuPCmUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=robert+longo+men+in+cities&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoFCAAQgAQ6CAgAEIAEELEDOgQIABBDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToHCAAQsQMQQzoGCAAQCBAeOgQIABAYUJsSWL5FYMZHaABwAHgAgAHHAYgBqRiSAQQxLjI2mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=we63YfS1IY25-gTrn6qoBg&bih=780&biw=1536&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS865US865) series seem to be a pretty good match to your description of the photos. From the Wikipedia page:

> Longo became first well known in the 1980s for his Men in the Cities
> drawing and print series, which depict sharply dressed men and women
> writhing in contorted emotion

.

Comment: That was exactly it!! Thank you so much! :) For some reason I thought it was an "M" name but I stand corrected. Thank you!

Comment: @kellyandrews: There is certainly an **M** in **M**en in the Cities.